# ¿Como se usa el comando o código "commondialog" de la librería Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy tratando de entender los documentos oficiales y me topé con el módulo tkinter.commondialog. Nosé com se aplica o como se usa. Si bien sé que tengo que importarlo pero nose como se usa. Agradezco la ayuda que aporten

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Según [esta sección de la documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.commondialog) parece que está pensado para ser el código base para otros modulos, por lo que supongo que está pensado para uso interno de Tkinter, pero no estoy seguro de ello.